# While loop in root shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get data from a file which can be read by root only and do some operations on the data.

the code is

```
su -c "grep $variable $file | while read -r line; do echo $line | xargs -r umount -l; done"
```

but as I checked the while loop doesn't assign the line to `$line` variable and hence the umount doesn't work.

I don't want to use single quotes as the `$variable` and `$file` vars are declared outside the root shell.

Comment: Change `echo $line` to `echo \$line`

Comment: Also `xargs` in loop doesn't make sense. `grep ... | xargs -r umount -l` is probably enough. If only one argument is to be passed at a time, add `-n1` option to `xargs`. `$variable` and `$file` might also be worth expanding as quoted through `${variable@Q}` and `${file@Q}`.